# Как взять срез строки, начиная со предельных слов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список строк(каждая более 200 символов)
Необходимо проверить каждую строку на наличие определённых слов и взять срез в 5 символов с момента вхождения этих слов(включительно)

Например :
Ключевые слова: ‘что’, ‘в’

[‘Привет! Как дела, что делаешь?’, ‘а наши люди в булочную на такси не ездят’]

В первом случае должно возвращаться ‘что д’
Во втором - ‘в бул’

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема-то? Найти строку в строке, взять срез?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно при помощи регулярных выражений.

Опишу регекс:

- `(?= )` - positive lookahead - находим значение в скобках, потом отматываем анализатор к его началу;
- `\b \b` - ищем целые слова (флаг `re.UNICODE` нужен, чтобы срабатывало для кириллицы)
- `(?: )` - non-matching group - то, что в этих скобках - должно быть найдено, но не выводится в качестве отдельной группы
- `|` - или одно слово, или другое. Сюда можно добавлять ещё слов
- `.{5}` - выбираем 5 символов

---

```
import re

find_regex = re.compile(r'(?=\b(?:Что|в)\b).{5}', re.UNICODE|re.IGNORECASE)

lines = [
    'Привет! Как дела, что делаешь? Не ходи в кино!',
    'а наши люди в булочную на такси не ездят',
    'test'
]
matches = []
for line in lines:
    matches += re.findall(find_regex, line)
print(matches)
```

Результат:

```
['что д', 'в кин', 'в бул']
```

Здесь можно поэкспериментировать: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jM2FyO/1)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно постановка задания. Почему тогда в первом варианте не "вет! "? Ведь "в" входит в состав строки.
Но если Вам нужен именно такой ответ, то вот.

```
l = ['Привет! Как дела, что делаешь?', 'а наши люди в булочную на такси не ездят']
first, second = 'что', 'в'
for i in l:
  one = i.rfind(first)
  two = i.rfind(second)
  if one > two:
    if one != -1:
      print(i[one:one+5])
    else:
      print(i[two:two+5])
  elif one < two:
    if two != -1:
      print(i[two:two+5])
    else:
      print(i[one:one+5])
```